# ManAxisAlignment.spaceBetween (row) not working as it should?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code:

```
_buildWave() {
    return Container(
      height: 100.0,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            WaveWidget(
              config: CustomConfig(
                  colors: helpers.waveColors,
                  durations: [32000, 21000, 25000, 5000],
                  heightPercentages: [0.25, 0.26, 0.28, 0.31]),
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              size: Size(double.infinity, double.infinity),
              waveAmplitude: 0,
            ),
            Container(
              child: Positioned(
                bottom: 15,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 5, 0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            Icon(LineIcons.streetView, size: 20),
                            SizedBox(width: 5),
                            Text(
                              "Left",
                              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [Text("Right")],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The intention is to place the LEFT and RIGHT text on yes, the left and right side. Now, I know this can be done using MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween but for some reason it won't work. I'm getting no errors.

Image is what I'm getting right now:

[image: Issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that is because you have kept the Row Widget inside Stack Widget, try giving the full width to the Positioned Widget present inside the Stack Widget like below and also remove the Container Widget:

```
       child: Stack(
          children: [
            WaveWidget(
              config: CustomConfig(
                  colors: helpers.waveColors,
                  durations: [32000, 21000, 25000, 5000],
                  heightPercentages: [0.25, 0.26, 0.28, 0.31]),
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              size: Size(double.infinity, double.infinity),
              waveAmplitude: 0,
            ),
            Positioned(

                // Here
                left: 0.0,
                right: 0.0,
                //

                bottom: 15,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 5, 0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            Icon(LineIcons.streetView, size: 20),
                            SizedBox(width: 5),
                            Text(
                              "Left",
                              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [Text("Right")],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
```

Comment: Works! Appreciate it!